# Google Sign-In for Server-Side Apps for .Net core

Tags: google-api, google-sso

I want to implement Google Sign-In for Server-Side Apps (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) in .Net Core - Web API or MVC. Is there any SDK for this?

Comment: Like Asp .net core? or are you talking about doing this from a backend service?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, a backend Web API. The document page shows code for Java & Python only.

Comment: Is this a single acount your accessing or are you trying to access user data?  If its user data then your going to have to have some kind of website set up to request access from them and then store the refresh token some place your back end web api can access it.

Comment: @DaImTo The code mentioned in the provided link relates to Java. But, such classes are not available in .Net using Google's SDK. So, I just want to achieve the same code but in .NET. If you are aware which Google's SDK or nuget package I need to install, then it will be very helpful.